Helm Library Chart Transitive Dependency Resolution from Umbrella Chart
I have an Umbrella Chart A that has a dependency on Chart B, which has a Library Chart C dependency.
So far it is that when doing helm dependency build or update Chart C is not pulled into Chart B and therefore the deployment can't proceed.
Is that the expected behavior

If A depends on B depends on C, then when you run help dep build from A you should see a downloaded charts/C.tgz, but nothing underneath B.  Does this introduce a problem?  Is this related to your Helm template code at all, or is it purely a deployment or automation problem?  If it's code related, do you have a [mcve]?  (I've had several bad experiences around umbrella charts, mostly due to Helm's handling of second- and third-level dependencies like this.)
